# Change Img src value with phantom js

Tags: phantomjs

I'm trying to change a src element in an img tag with phantom js and for some reason I can't get it.  I've checked all over google and info on this is scarce.  Here's what I've tried:

```
document.getElementById("licensePlateImg").setAttribute("src", "blahblahblah.jpg")
```

This one I didn't think would work but tried any how:

```
document.getElementById("licensePlateImg").img.setAttribute("src", "blahblahblah")
```

no success with this either.

```
document.getElementById("licensePlateImg").find("img").attr("src", "blahblahblah");
```

This is the div I need to change:

I can't use jquery for this.

Comment: Have you verified that the element is getting selected properly?

Comment: By that do you mean if the element is there?  @Brad  I'm not sure how to confirm it's being selected.  I think that's part of the problem.

Comment: Use your developer tools and try something like `console.log(document.getElementById('licensePlateImg'));`.

Comment: Ok I'm using another library so I need to add this into a phantom js call back.  Do you know which call back I would use for soemthing like "if this document id loaded"? @Brad